# Are those functions Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f,g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 , \text{ if } x \in (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \\ \frac{1}{q}, \text{ if } x =\frac{p}{q} \text{ irreductible fraction with }q>0 \end{cases}$$
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}0, \text{ if } x=0 \\ 1, \text{ if } 0 < x \leq 1\end{cases}$$

Are those functions Riemann integrable? What about the composite $g\circ f$?

I couldn't think of anything that shows that, but i think that $f$ and $g$ are integrable, but $g \circ f$ isn't. Can anyone explain how I start to think in that question? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, regarding your $f(x)$, see [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).

Comment: Both these functions $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable. How you'd prove/reason this depends on how much machinery you're familiar with. For example, $g$ is discountinuous at one point in $[0,1]$. A function that is discountinuous at finitely many points is integrable. More generally, a function discontinuous at countably many points is also integrable. This explains the integrability of $f$. I'll let you think about the composite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, how you should go about proving this depends on the machinery you are familiar with.

I believe that the most common approach in undergraduate courses is to use upper and lower sums. I have therefore sketched a solution which uses this definition of the Riemann integral.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a partition of $I = [0,1]$.

Notice that,
$$
 L_\alpha(f; \mathcal{P}) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\inf_{x \in [x_{k-1}, x_k]} f(x)\right)\cdot\left[(x_k) - (x_{k-1})\right] = 0.
 $$

Since this is valid for any partition of the unit interval, it follows that the lower integral is $0$.

In order to show that $f$ is integrable, fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and find a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $I$ such that
$$
  U_\alpha(f; \mathcal{P}) - L_\alpha(f; \mathcal{P}) = U_\alpha(f; \mathcal{P}) < \varepsilon.
 $$

To do this, pick $q\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
  \frac{1}{q} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}
 $$
and notice that the set of point
$$
  S_q:=\left\{x\in [0,1] : f(x)\geq \frac{1}{q}\right\}
 $$
is finite of cardinality $M$.

Then explain why you can pick partition $\mathcal{P} = \{x_0, \dots, x_n\}$ such that

- $x_k\not\in S_q$ for each $k$, except possibly $k=0$ and $k=n$.
- There holds: $$
    (x_k) - (x_{k-1}) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2M}.
   $$

You can now bound the upper $U_\alpha(f; \mathcal{P})$ by $\varepsilon$. To do this, you will have to split your sum into two parts (the subintervals that contain elements of $S_q$ and those that do not).

The composition $g\circ f$ is the Dirichlet function. Using that the rationals (and the irrationals) are dense, you should be able to show that the upper integral evaluates to $1$ while the lower integral evaluates to $0$. In particular, the function is not Riemann integrable.

NOTE: The goal of this problem is to show you that the composition of Riemann integral functions need not be Riemann integrable.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!